Recursively extract zip archive on synology nas (notion)
I'm working with a Synology NAS. I have a notion backup ZIP file (a ZIP file containing another ZIP file). The file is big so I want to script unzipping so first the outer zip gets extracted and then the inner zip automatically without intervention. The usual unzip utility is not available for synology NAS.
I need to automate the process of extracting these nested ZIP files using a Bash script. I realized have 7z installed on my NAS but am unsure how to handle nested archives effectively. How can I recursively extract all nested ZIP files using 7z?
